# LINQ problem on remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using LINQ expressions in my code

like this

var obj = Collection.Single(collection => (collection.ShortName.Equals("AAA")));

The problem is that this line works fine for me, no problems.

But when I upload the same executable to some remote machine with same 32 bit Windows XP. The code execution is just stopping at this line of source.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Does it throw an exception, or just stop?

Comment: The code is running in Thread, the thread is just stopping after this line. No code is executed after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that the thread is "stopping". If an exception is thrown in a thread it will terminate, is this what you mean by "stopping"? Single() will throw if either none or more than one element is present, and i think that this might be what is going on..

Are you certain that the collection contains exactly one matching element at all times?

Note: Read Eric Lipperts link. If possible, you could run it on a BackgroundWorker, and check the Error property of the eventargs when the thread exits.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Ok I agree but where the exception goes?

Comment: Eric Lippert says ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/25/careful-with-that-axe-part-two-what-about-exceptions.aspx